# Grep command to search and extract port number

Tags: python, linux, xcode, grep, ansible

I have a few IP Address which im trying to gather the last 4 digits (port numbers)

*IE*... the IP ADDRESS and format is like:    123.123.13.3:8080",

As you can see there is a  `:`   at the start of the port number and at end there is      `",`

I'm trying the use a grep to state - grep anything which as `:` at the end and at the end `"` or and `,`

Could you please help?

Comment: Not clear what you asking. What is your workflow? Did some `grep` command like: `grep '.*:.*[",]$'` would do the job?

Comment: Sorry about question

Comment: netstat -tulnp | awk '{print $4}' | grep '.*:.*[",]$'
This is my command (with you part included)

Comment: I have done a print$4 for the correct column. just trying to get the port numbers. I will cp the input here but make up the IP Addresses

Comment: "1.1.1.1:5555",
        ":::11111",
        ":::11",
        "01.01.01.01:68",
        "011.1.1.1:111",
        "79.64.4.4:123",

This is an example and im trying to gather the last numbers of all the IP Addresses

They all start with : and end with a , or '

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your IP addresses are stored in a file, you can use `sed` to get what you want:

```
sed -n 's/.*:\([^",]*\)[",]*$/\1/p' IP_FILE
```

With parameters/commands to seed:

- `-n`: no print
- `...../p`: print only matches
- `s/...`: substitute
- `.*:\[^",][",]*$`; match all characters after a `:` which are not `"` or `,`, followed by `"` or `,`, and by end of line (`$`)
- `\1`: print what is between parenthesis.

Comment: for the moment I would like them to just be readable on the screen so I was thinking just grep them but I think I need to re think how to gather them

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `cut` command for this by saving the content in a file.

```
cut -d ':' -f2 /tmp/abc | cut -c1-4
8080
```

or

```
cat /tmp/abc | cut -d ':' -f2 | cut -c1-4
8080
```